# jQuery.load() is loading the page, but the embed javascript inside the loaded page is giving Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

So here is the scenario:

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 2 under the 4.0 framework and have a page that calls the $.load on an Action link.  This is all fine, it works as expected.  The page that is loading has a call to a javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js"/>
```

This is failing and saying that "Method Not Allowed" as it is trying to POST this call instead of GET.  I can see this happening with firebug.

I have another js file in the project that is included on all pages with a call to:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 60 * 1000
});
```

this is so that I don't have to make all of my $.ajax calls explicitly POST.  If I change this to GET the $.load call works great.  However, most of the rest of the site does not as Microsoft retired the GET method from MCV 2 or the 4.0 framework (I don't really remember which).

I would rather not change all the $.ajax calls to POST explicitly, but I'm not sure what else to do at this point, so I was hoping to find an answer here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The page that is loading has a call to a javascript file:

Don't inject HTML with `<script>` tags into the document using `load()` or `html()`. It's highly unreliable cross-browser (and in jQuery, which may remove script tags completely depending on the situation), and even when it works it can cause you real confusion by loading the same script twice, potentially giving you duplicate definitions and handlers. (And of course, any script that relies on being executed at page load time is doomed.)

If some script needs to be executed after a page load, either keep that code in static script and execute it in the `ajax`/`load` callback function, or have the server return a JSON object containing the code in a string separately from the HTML.

> I would rather not change all the $.ajax calls to POST explicitly

If you really must try to load `<script>` tags dynamically you would have to... either that or change the call to `ajax()` in jQuery-1.4.3.js line 4978 to include an explicit `type: 'GET'` setting. Arguably it's a jQuery bug that this isn't included. But on the other hand the whole premise of AJAX-loading `<script>` is flawed.

Comment: I included the js file on the original page and then used $.getScript to call the actual script that needed to be run that was in different script tags in the page that I was loading.  Your answer was very helpful in seeing how everything worked together.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts. According to the [documentation for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

How are you calling .load()? If you use an object as the second parameter, it will use a POST.

If you are using .load correctly and it is the ajaxSetup that is causing the problem, maybe you could change the ajaxSetup type to GET temporarily while the load is taking place and then set it back to POST. Just an idea.

Comment: According to firebug, it is doing a GET on the actual request, but then doing a POST to the js file.  Weird, I know.

Comment: That is very strange. Did you try temporarily setting the global settings to "GET" during the load?

Comment: Yes, when I do that everything works as expected.  However, other things in the site break due to GET not being supported anymore in MVC 2 or .NET 4 (Like I said, I don't remember which because we added both in the course of this project)

Comment: I would say look at bobince's answer. Looks like your options are pretty limited. If you run out of options and really don't want to change the way your page works, you could always punt and go with an iframe..